# Print all possible words from phone number digits

Tags: algorithm

My question is How many words are possible with seven digits with each digit representing n letters? When we press 2,3,4 while typing a text possible words which can be formed are (Alphabetical order):

if input number is 234, 
adg adh adi aeg aeh aei afg afh afi bdg bdh bdi beg beh bei bfg bfh bfi cdg cdh cdi ceg ceh cei cfg cfh cfi

Comment: You talking about old phones where each digit on the phone has 3 letters ?

Comment: Yes i am taking about old phone.

Comment: @SuryaPrakashKushawah I hope it'll help check [this](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-possible-words-phone-digits/).

Answer (score 2):

Recursive solution:

```
void printAllWordsFromPhoneNumber(string phonenumber)
{
    printAllWordsFromPrefixAndPhoneNumber("", phonenumber);
}

string getLettersForNumber(char digit)
{
    string [] table = {"", "", "ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "JKL", "MNO", "PQRS", "TUV", "WXYZ"};
    bool valid = ((digit >= '0') && (digit <= '9'));
    return valid ? table[digit-'0'] : "";
}

void printAllWordsFromPrefixAndPhoneNumber(string prefix, string remaining)
{
   if ( (remaining == null) || (remaining.length()==0) )
   {
       System.out.println(prefix);
   }
   else
   {
       string chars_in_digit = getLettersForNumber(remaining.charAt(0));

       for (int i = 0; i < chars_in_digit.length(); i++)
       {
           string newprefix = prefix + chars_in_digit.charAt(i);
           string newremaining = remaining.substr(1);
           printAllWordsFromPrefixAndPhoneNumber(newprefix, newremaining);
       }

       // special case for "0" and "1" since neither has any letters associated with them.
       if (chars_in_digit.length() == 0)
       {
           printAllWordsFromPrefixAndPhoneNumber(prefix, remaining.substr(1));
       }

   }
}
```

Comment: please do upvote this question

Answer (score -1):

// call this

```
   List<String> perms = permutation("", "abc");
   // instead of "abc write your 7 digit number

            String[] array = new String[perms.size()];
            for (int i = 0; i < perms.size(); i++) {
                array[i] = perms.get(i);
            }

            int x = array.length;

            for (final String anArray : array) {
                System.out.println(anArray);
            }
```

// method for it

```
private static List<String> permutation(String prefix, String str) {
        List<String> permutations = new ArrayList<>();
        int n = str.length();
        if (n == 0) {
            permutations.add(prefix);
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                permutations.addAll(permutation(prefix + str.charAt(i), str.substring(i + 1, n) + str.substring(0, i)));
            }
        }
        return permutations;
    }
```